# What is input rate?

Tags: infinifactory

I just noticed a number (was it always there?) in the HUD 'input rate' you can adjust with the square brackets keys. What is it, what does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input rate is the rate at which raw materials are put into the system, this is done by "input" multi-blocks which can only have their rate changed in the level editor. (So no, it wasn't always there)